# Kotlin: Upcast and sealed classes

Tags: kotlin

I'm using the FunKTionale library to perform pattern matching. Then, when I initialize a variable as follows:

```
private lateinit var socket = Option.None
```

The transformation below is not possible:

```
socket = socket.map {
    selectedDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID).apply {
    connect()
    }
}
```

Because the type of socket is

```
Option.None
```

But if I initialize the socket variable as

```
private lateinit var socket: Option<BluetoothSocket> = Option.None
```

The map function works. The Option.None object extends

```
Option<Nothing>
```

and was casted (in this case) to

```
Option<BluetoothSocket>
```

So, how is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that when you omit the field type, the most specific type is inferred from the initial value type. To declare a field with some less specific type one should specify it explicitly.

Assuming that the hierarchy looks like this in your case:

```
Any -> ... -> Option -> Option.None
```

So, when the initial value has type `Option.None`, it is also inferred for the field type, and the field won't be able to store values of a more general type `Option`.

To make field type `Option` or something more general up to `Any` you have to specify it explicitly.

To make it more clear, this should also work in your case:

```
var socket = Option.None as Option<Socket>
```

Here, type of `Option.None as Option<Socket>` is not `Option.None` but `Option`.
However, the code is more readable when you specify the type of the field in complex hierarchy cases.

Comment: I get it, but how Option<Nothing> (which is the type of Option.None) can be casted to Option<BluetoothSocket>?

Comment: @JulysPablo, it is in the type system: just as `Any` is a super type of any other (non-nullable) type, `Nothing` is a subtype of any other type. According to this, the example code is valid: 
`val lst: List<Int> = listOf<Nothing>()`. And, for example, the `throw` expressions have type `Nothing`.

Comment: Thank you @hotkey. I didn't know that Nothing is a subtype of any other type